# Find out Thingsboard scriptID errors from thingsboard.log

Tags: thingsboard

How to find out which script is generating the below error?

I get

> 2022-10-03 16:15:25,109 [nioEventLoopGroup-4-4] WARN
> o.t.js.api.AbstractJsInvokeService - Script invocation is blocked due
> to maximum error count 3, scriptId
> 78aee53d-f8b0-4024-ad50-bb7f044ea920!

but can't succeed to point out which script is referenced by the above scriptId.

Apparently it's not a Data converter scrit nor a Rule chain node...

Anyone can help?

Seppax

Comment: However, I would enable debug mode for all Rule Chain nodes where JS scripts are used, and check *Events* tab whether the errors is present or not.

Comment: There's no way according to the TB helpdesk that we engaged, they will put this fix on the dev backlog, hopefully implemented in a coming release